# Magento Value '29,990000' has to be numeric

Tags: php, magento, ubuntu, zend-server

I just updated my zendserver. then when I tried to access `/admin` on my magento local I get the following error:

> Value '29,990000' has to be numeric

I tried to replace

```
$price = sprintf("%f", $price);
```

with

```
$price = (float) $price;
```

in `app/code/core/Mage/Directory/Model/Currency.php`
but the above didn't work at all.

Then I tried to change `precision = 14` to `precision = 8` in my `php.ini`
but still I could find a solution on this issue

Comment: Is that really a comma?  Does a comma mean "decimal point" in your country?

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this by downgrading my PHP from PHP 5.5 to 5.3

Comment: Were you not using the Zend Server supplied PHP?  Normally, you pick the version of PHP you are going to use when you select your Zend Server version...